# Laravel model relationship between parent & children

Tags: laravel, model

I am developing web app using Laravel 8 , and mostly developing use model.
I have a problem for now get some information.

-user_role table

```
----------------------------------
id    user_id     role_id     cost 
----------------------------------
1       1           1          20
2       1           2          30
3       2           1          10
.
.
.
```

-car table

```
-----------------------------------
id    car_name     user_id  role_id
1       car_1         1        1
2       car_2         2        1
.
.
.
```

here , I want to get cost info from car table using user_id and role_id

how can I get cost information?

Help me please

Answer (score -1):

```
Model::with('pivote_table')->where('user_id',1)->get();
```

Comment: not working .........

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.